# Increase range of date options in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jquery's datepicker for users to select their DOB. I set the default to 01/01/1980 so that its a little easier to select your DOB (our constraint is that your age > 18 years.

I set minDate to be 100 years in the past from today. When I toggle the datepicker, the minimum date appears to be 1970. If I select it, close the datepicker, and open it again, I can go further back (to select 1960 for example). I would like to allow users to select a date preceding 1970 without having to do this.

[image: 1970 constrained]

**Code:**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#id_date_of_birth" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "-18Y",
    minDate: "-100Y",
    defaultDate: '01/01/1980'
   });
 });
```

Comment: I ended up removing this and using 3 separate fields for month, day, year. Easier to select DOB and less page load (remove jquery ui dependency): http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49741/when-and-why-should-date-pickers-be-used

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the range cap happens to be about an 18 year split.
That might be related to your `maxDate`

Try omitting the `maxDate` or increasing it to see if you're still capped at 1970 on the first opening of the dropdown.

If that works, you can play with your `defaultDate` and `maxDate` to get the desired range.

From the Docs:

> **maxDate**
>
> The maximum selectable date. When set to null, there is no maximum.
> Multiple types supported:
>
> Date: A date object containing the maximum date.
>
> Number: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
>
> String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate